# Easiest way to link text and a picture together to keep track of them in PHP

Tags: php

So I'm building a test website as a proof-of-concept in PHP. The user is able to upload a picture and submit text along with the picture. What is an easy way to keep track of them with only PHP (no MySQL)?

Comment: you can use array to store data .. . but then this is not persistence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a directory for the user on your host. Store the images in there. To prevent duplicates, add timestamps to the filenames. Or calculate a file hash and add that to the name. Store the additional text as a plain text file in the same location. You'll end up with something like

```
+ users
|_ Chris
| \_ image42_ad4feeb234.png
| |_ image42_ad4feeb234.txt
| |_ more images…
|_ another user
|_ and so on
```

As an alternative, create a single large XML file and put everything in there, e.g. images and text together:

```
<images>
  <image user="Chris">
    <base64>the image data</base64>
    <text>Some info about the image</text>
  </image>
  <image user="John">
    <base64>the image data</base64>
    <text>Some info about the image</text>
  </image>
  … more images
</images>
```

You will need to base64 encode the images in order to store them in the XML file. Note that this will result in a rather large file. You can easily read and write the XML file with PHP's DOM library.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with maintaining a text file. Which will hold your image name and text related to it, as a key value pair(like an Array).

```
[image_1] => "Text 1"
[image_2] => "Text 2"
```

But it won't be consistent in case where you get any duplicate image name and different text with it.